# Anybody written a dictionary (hashmap) in ANSI C?

Tags: c, dictionary, hashmap

I just wondered if someone could give me some pointers (no pun intended) how to do this?

I want to set aside 4GB of ram in order to map numbers to memory which saves me traversing a linked list checking if they are there.

So instead of having (1,2,3,4,8,34,543,2343) and traversing 8 elements to verify that '2343' is in the list, i want to be able to look up the key '2343' in O(1) time?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Begin with the first step: Learn and read about them. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashmap

Comment: You want a bit array, not a hash.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise embedding [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) in your project. Easy to embed and completely ANSI C with one very flexible garbage collected data structure (a Lua table/aka hashmap). You can always strip out the bits that you don't need, but even if you don't Lua is tiny.

Lua has a stack based API which isn't too hard to follow:

```
  lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();  // make a new lua state
  lua_newtable(L);  // pushes a new table to the top of the stack (position 1)

  // storing values
  lua_pushinteger(2343); // key: 2343
  lua_pushboolean(1);    // value: true
  lua_settable(L, 1);   // pop key/value, store in table at position 1

  // retrieving values
  lua_pushinteger(2343); // key we're looking for
  lua_gettable(L, 1);   // get from table at top of stack - 2; pops key
  if (lua_toboolean(L, -1))  // is it a true value?
  {
    // executes; we know 2343 is true as we pushed it just above
  }
  lua_pop(L, 1);  // pop it off the stack; only our table remains
```

And you can iterate over the values as well, possibly doing away with the need of your linked list (but the order of the iteration is non-determinate). Full manual [here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to check if the number exists in the list, the you can try to make a Bitmap.

If the numbers are going to be sparsely spread out over a large range like 100,000 values in the range 0-4billion then a Hashtable would be faster.  For a C implementation of a Hashtable [take a look at GLib's Hashtable](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html).

A Bitmap could hold numbers 0-4,294,967,295 using only 512Mbytes of ram.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define BITMAP_TEST 1

#define BITMAP_32_WORD 1

typedef struct Bitmap Bitmap;
#if BITMAP_32_WORD
#define BITWORD_BITS_SHIFT 5
typedef uint32_t Bitword;
#else
#define BITWORD_BITS_SHIFT 6
typedef uint64_t Bitword;
#endif
#define BITWORD_BITS (sizeof(Bitword) * 8)
#define BITWORD_BITS_MASK (BITWORD_BITS - 1)
#define BITWORD_MULT(bit)  ((bit + (BITWORD_BITS_MASK)) & ~(BITWORD_BITS_MASK))
#define BITWORD_TEST(bword, bit) ((bword >> bit) & 1)

#define BITMAP_WORD_COUNT(bit) (BITWORD_MULT(bit) >> BITWORD_BITS_SHIFT)


struct Bitmap {
    size_t  length;
    Bitword *bitmap;
};

extern Bitmap *bitmap_new(size_t len) {
    Bitmap *bitmap = malloc(sizeof(Bitmap));
    bitmap->length = len;
    bitmap->bitmap = calloc(BITMAP_WORD_COUNT(len),sizeof(Bitword));
    return bitmap;
}

extern void bitmap_free(Bitmap *bitmap) {
    free(bitmap->bitmap);
    free(bitmap);
}

extern void bitmap_set(Bitmap *bitmap, size_t bit) {
    assert(bit < bitmap->length);
    bitmap->bitmap[(bit >> BITWORD_BITS_SHIFT)] |= ((Bitword)1 << (bit & BITWORD_BITS_MASK));
}

extern void bitmap_unset(Bitmap *bitmap, size_t bit) {
    assert(bit < bitmap->length);
    bitmap->bitmap[(bit >> BITWORD_BITS_SHIFT)] &= ~((Bitword)1 << (bit & BITWORD_BITS_MASK));
}

extern bool bitmap_test(Bitmap *bitmap, size_t bit) {
    assert(bit < bitmap->length);
    Bitword bword = bitmap->bitmap[(bit >> BITWORD_BITS_SHIFT)];
    return BITWORD_TEST(bword, (bit & BITWORD_BITS_MASK));
}

#ifdef BITMAP_TEST
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_VALUE (2343 + 1)
static const uint32_t test_values[] = { 1,2,3,4,8,34,543,2343 };
#define test_values_len (sizeof(test_values)/sizeof(uint32_t))

static void set_values(Bitmap *bitmap, const uint32_t *values, int len) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < len; i++) {
        bitmap_set(bitmap, values[i]);
    }
}

static void unset_values(Bitmap *bitmap, const uint32_t *values, int len) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < len; i++) {
        bitmap_unset(bitmap, values[i]);
    }
}

static void check_values(Bitmap *bitmap, const uint32_t *values, int len, bool is_set) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < len; i++) {
        assert(bitmap_test(bitmap, values[i]) == is_set);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Bitmap *bitmap = bitmap_new(MAX_VALUE);

    set_values(bitmap, test_values, test_values_len);

    check_values(bitmap, test_values, test_values_len, true);

    unset_values(bitmap, test_values, test_values_len);

    check_values(bitmap, test_values, test_values_len, false);

    bitmap_free(bitmap);
    return 0;
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are 32 bits you don't even need hashing, just use an array.

Comment: They may be 32bits to begin with, but not later on. Im curious though, if they were 32 bits why could i use an array for instant look-up?

Comment: If you knew the maximum value was small, create an array with a bit (or for simplicity, a byte) for every possible value, and set it to 1 to indicate presence in the linked list. Constant time lookup, but impractical if you have billions of possible values..

Answer (score 0):

A hashtable is actually only O(1) when there are no keys that have the same hash.

For an easy short version of a hashtable in C look here:
http://pokristensson.com/strmap.html

Comment: So do you recommend using hash table for this problem, or not?